# How can show all value from db table in linked list python using postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

```
def Display(self):

    # current is assign head value

    current = self.head

    # if head is empty it excute this statment of empty list

    if self.head is None:
        print("--------- Sorry it's an Empty List ---------")
        return
    print(
        "--------------- ALL Account HOlder List ---------------\n Account_No      |      Name      |      "
        "Contact_No      |      Type      |      Amount|      Password")




    # if list  is not none it excute thst statment and show the attribute of account

    while current is not None:
        print("   ", current.number, "                ", current.name, "              ", current.contact,
              "                ", current.type, "             ", current.amount, "         ", current.password)
        cur.execute("SELECT id, name, contact, type, amount, password FROM customer ")
        conn.commit()
        current = current.next
```

it show nothing with this method but when i run this query in console it show all values from table. even i close program and run again it also show nothing when i run display function